# Getting exception when dealing with MySql.Data.EntityFramework with optional child

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

#### Backstory

I am having an odd issue with a pet project. My program stores various information about a prop (which is just a physical item in a game I play). Of that information, I was storing a thumbnail along with the prop. The entity at the time looked like:

```
public class PropItem
{
    ...
    public string ThumbnailMimeType { get; set; }
    public byte[] ThumbnailContent { get; set; }
    public PropItem()
    {
        ...
        this.ThumbnailMimeType = string.Empty;
        this.ThumbnailContent = null;
    }
}
```

I then decided I wanted to keep an original image and a thumbnail image, so I created a `PropMediaItem` and replaced the `PropItem.ThumbnnailMimeType` and `PropItem.ThumbnnailContent` properties on `PropItem`. This took the form of:

```
public class PropItem
{
    ...
    public PropMediaItem ThumbnailImage { get; set; }
    public PropMediaItem OriginalImage { get; set; }
    public PropItem()
    {
        ...
        this.ThumbnailImage = null;
        this.OriginalImage = null;
    }
}

public class PropMediaItem
{
    ...
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    public PropMediaItem()
    {
        ...
        this.MimeType = string.Empty;
        this.Content = null;
    }
}
```

And I updated `DbContext.OnModelCreating` to be:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //
    // Props
    modelBuilder.Entity<PropItem>().ToTable("Props");
    modelBuilder.Entity<PropItem>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<PropItem>().HasOptional(x => x.ThumbnailImage);
    modelBuilder.Entity<PropItem>().HasOptional(x => x.OriginalImage);

    modelBuilder.Entity<PropMediaItem>().ToTable("PropMedia");
    modelBuilder.Entity<PropMediaItem>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
}
```

#### The Error

However, after making the change and updating the database, anytime I attempt to get the props using the database context (`context.Props.Include("ThumbnailImage").ToList()`), I get the following error:

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Non-negative number required.
Parameter name: count]
   System.Text.EncodingNLS.GetString(Byte[] bytes, Int32 index, Int32 count) +12533943
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadColumnValue(Int32 index, MySqlField field, IMySqlValue valObject) +217
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.ReadColumnData(Boolean outputParms) +73
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.NextRow(CommandBehavior behavior) +158
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Read() +116
   MySql.Data.EntityFramework.EFMySqlDataReader.Read() +13
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead() +36

[EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.HandleReaderException(Exception e) +145
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead() +49
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext() +50
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +112
   FiveMModdingResource.Index.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Repository\Visual Studio\website\website\index.aspx.cs:21
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +52
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +97
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +61
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +693
```

I basically can't get the context to return items now without throwing this error. Doesn't matter how I materialize the query.

#### What I tried

Initially, I reverted back to the original structure to make sure that change is what caused it and the application began working again. For funsies, I decided to reimplement the change but this time remove the new `PropMediaItem` properties from the `PropItem` entity and it loads just fine without the additional image entities.

It appears that when the parent has an optional relationship with a child and the child doesn't exist, it is failing to load. The only thing I can think of doing at the moment would be putting the properties directly on the `PropItem` but that just feels like a gross workaround.

My project is an ASP.NET WebForm app using .NET 4.7.2, EntityFramework 6.4.4, and MySql.Data.EntityFramework 8.0.22. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should check which version of MySQL Connector/NET you have installed on your machine (I'm experienced the same problem while using MySql.Data.EntityFramework 8.0.22 and MySQL Connector/NET 8.0.21).

Then, read the following guide and check carefully your .config file:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html